# Static Read Only SQLite3 Database in Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, heroku, sqlite

I will try my best to explain my issue.

I have a SQLite3 database file of about 50,000 records that I compiled and use in my app. This database is read only and is only used to query and pull data from. I created a model for it in rails and it looks like this.

```
class Locations < ActiveRecord::Base

  establish_connection(
     :adapter => 'sqlite3',
     :database => 'db/locs.sqlite3'
  )
  set_table_name "Locations"

end
```

Everything works great on the development end, but fails when I deploy to Heroku. I'm assuming the issue is that Heroku runs on Postrgres but I need this database to be separate from the main production database and I don't need something fancy. All I need is for the app to query some records from this file.

Is there a solution out there? Thanks

Comment: I don't think that Heroku supports sqlite3 databases.Maybe I'm wrong but you can find it here: stackoverflow.com/questions/3897431/deploying-ror-app-to-heroku-with-sqlite3-fails

Comment: Heroku doesn't support SQLite. Your app is either failing to install the `sqlite3` gem on push because Heroku won't let you, or you don't have `sqlite3` listed in production group in your Gemfile (and even if you did, it would then fail to install anyway).

Either way, there is no way to get SQLite running on Heroku. You may consider Redis as a separate backend, which is offered by Heroku and 3rd party providers. Or why not just load the data from SQLite into Heroku's PostgreSQL, under a different table(s)?

Answer (score 2):

Allowing SQLite3 read only can be enabled by following the steps from this git repo.

https://github.com/yotsumoto/heroku-buildpack-ruby-with-sqlite3

After running:

```
$ heroku config:set BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/yotsumoto/heroku-buildpack-ruby-with-sqlite3
```

I was able to `git push heroku master` with `gem 'sqlite3'` still in the Gemfile.

Answer (score -1):

I'm really not understanding your question but I'm assuming you want to use sq in dev & testing but want to use postrgres in product, correct? If so, the code below should help. Switching from sqlite to pg is rather seamless so you shouldn't have a problem doing so.

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end
```

Comment: Wait, just looked over your model again & read your q again. What does your .yml look like?

Comment: My .yml hasn't been touched. Because I read that Heroku overwrites your database.yml when you deploy.

Comment: Yea, I have not the slightest clue as to what you're trying to do. Why not just switch to pg? It's easy & I'm pretty certain that heroku doesn't support sqlite

Answer (score -2):

The simple answer to your question is it's not possible to do what you're trying to do. Heroku don't have necessary prerequisites installed to even let you install the sqlite gem.